# Displaying DataTable Columns Side-By-Side C# Console Application

Tags: c#, datatable

I am completely new at coding. I felt like I was learning quickly and then of course was humbled by all there is in this world. I am currently trying to figure out if you can print DataTable Columns beside each other instead of up and down.

Here is some code that I wrote(experimenting because I feel like I have no idea anymore):

```
private void DataClaimsTable()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Queue<Claims> allInQueue = _claimsRepo.GetClaims();
            DataTable claimsDT = new DataTable("Komodo Insurance Claims");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (claimsDT.TableName.Length / 2)) + "}", claimsDT));
            Console.ResetColor();
            DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("Claim ID", typeof(int));
            DataColumn typeColumn = new DataColumn("Claim Type", typeof(Enum));
            DataColumn descriptionColumn = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
            DataColumn amountColumn = new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            DataColumn accidentColumn = new DataColumn("Date of Accident", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn claimColumn = new DataColumn("Date of Claim", typeof(DateTime));
            DataColumn validColumn = new DataColumn("Valid Claim", typeof(bool));
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(idColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(typeColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(descriptionColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(amountColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(accidentColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(claimColumn);
            claimsDT.Columns.Add(validColumn);
            DataRow idRow;
            Console.WriteLine(idColumn);
            foreach (Claims idPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                idRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                idRow["Claim ID"] = idPrint.ClaimID;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(idRow);
                Console.WriteLine(idRow[0]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow typeRow;
            Console.WriteLine(typeColumn);
            foreach (Claims typePrint in allInQueue)
            {
                typeRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                typeRow["Claim Type"] = typePrint.ClaimType;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(typeRow);
                Console.WriteLine(typeRow[1]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow descriptionRow;
            Console.WriteLine(descriptionColumn);
            foreach (Claims descriptionPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                descriptionRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                descriptionRow["Description"] = descriptionPrint.ClaimDescription;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(descriptionRow);
                Console.WriteLine(descriptionRow[2]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow amountRow;
            Console.WriteLine(amountColumn);
            foreach (Claims amountPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                amountRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                amountRow["Amount"] = amountPrint.ClaimAmount;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(amountRow);
                Console.WriteLine(amountRow[3]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow dateOfAccidentRow;
            Console.WriteLine(accidentColumn);
            foreach (Claims dateOfAccidentPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                dateOfAccidentRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                dateOfAccidentRow["Date of Accident"] = dateOfAccidentPrint.DateOfAccident;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(dateOfAccidentRow);
                Console.WriteLine(dateOfAccidentRow[4]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow dateOfClaimRow;
            Console.WriteLine(claimColumn);
            foreach (Claims dateOfClaimPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                dateOfClaimRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                dateOfClaimRow["Date of Claim"] = dateOfClaimPrint.DateOfClaim;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(dateOfClaimRow);
                Console.WriteLine(dateOfClaimRow[5]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            DataRow isValidRow;
            Console.WriteLine(validColumn);
            foreach (Claims isValidPrint in allInQueue)
            {
                isValidRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
                isValidRow["Valid Claim"] = isValidPrint.IsValid;
                claimsDT.Rows.Add(isValidRow);
                Console.WriteLine(isValidRow[6]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Output:

```
                                                Komodo Insurance Claims
Claim ID
1
2

Claim Type
Car
Home

Description
Rear bumper hit at traffic light.
Burned down due to unsupervised child.

Amount
3000.00
12000.00

Date of Accident
4/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/12/2020 12:00:00 AM

Date of Claim
4/9/2020 12:00:00 AM
4/14/2020 12:00:00 AM

Valid Claim
True
False


Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Do you want just to print Claims in SQL Table style? If yes, then you don't need DataTable, DataColumn and DataRow classes just to print the result in the console. In the first row you can print one by one property names of Claim class (see nameof expression). They are Column Headers. Terminate line. Then you can print one by one values of each Claim in allInQueue in order you picked to print Claim property names. To print something one by one use Console.Write(). Console.WriteLine() prints value and terminates line. Let me know if you get my idea. If not, I'll try to draw you an example.

Comment: I’m not fully sure but sql table seems right from my google search. I kinda see what you are saying. If you could just get me the general idea I’m sure I can figure it out from there... and thank you!!!

Comment: You might edit your question to say, "this is what the output looks like now, and this is what I want it to look like". It sounds like you want to pretty print a table. In general it's a matter of being patient and adding a bunch of | and _ characters and counting out spaces to make things look pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your existing code so that it can print the DataColumns beside each other.

Also, You don't need multiple `for` loops to map your `Queue` object to `DataRow`. Refer the below code for more information:

```
private static void DataClaimsTable()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Queue<Claims> allInQueue = _claimsRepo.GetClaims();
        DataTable claimsDT = new DataTable("Komodo Insurance Claims");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (claimsDT.TableName.Length / 2)) + "}", claimsDT));
        Console.ResetColor();
        DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("Claim ID", typeof(int));
        DataColumn typeColumn = new DataColumn("Claim Type", typeof(Enum));
        DataColumn descriptionColumn = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
        DataColumn amountColumn = new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(decimal));
        DataColumn accidentColumn = new DataColumn("Date of Accident", typeof(DateTime));
        DataColumn claimColumn = new DataColumn("Date of Claim", typeof(DateTime));
        DataColumn validColumn = new DataColumn("Valid Claim", typeof(bool));
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(idColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(typeColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(descriptionColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(amountColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(accidentColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(claimColumn);
        claimsDT.Columns.Add(validColumn);
        DataRow idRow;
        Console.WriteLine(idColumn);
        foreach (Claims idPrint in allInQueue)
        {
            idRow = claimsDT.NewRow();
            idRow["Claim ID"] = idPrint.ClaimID;
            idRow["Claim Type"] = idPrint.ClaimType;
            idRow["Description"] = idPrint.ClaimDescription;
            idRow["Amount"] = idPrint.ClaimAmount;
            idRow["Date of Accident"] = idPrint.DateOfAccident;
            idRow["Date of Claim"] = idPrint.DateOfClaim;
            idRow["Valid Claim"] = idPrint.IsValid;
            claimsDT.Rows.Add(idRow);
        }
        PrintDataTable(claimsDT);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void PrintDataTable(DataTable table)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,10}\t{1,10}\t{2,10}\t{3,10}\t{4,25}\t{5,25}\t{6,10}",
           "Claim ID",
           "Claim Type",
           "Description",
           "Amount",
           "Date of Accident",
           "Date of Claim",
           "Valid Claim"
           );
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}\t{1,10}\t{2,10}\t{3,10}\t{4,25}\t{5,25}\t{6,10}",
                row["Claim ID"],
                row["Claim Type"],
                row["Description"],
                row["Amount"],
                row["Date of Accident"],
                row["Date of Claim"],
                row["Valid Claim"]
                );
        }
    }
```

The `PrintDataTable` method will print your datatable in the tabular format. In this the string is formatted properly with `{0,10}` where 10 indicates number of spaces to allocate and `\t` for allocating tab space. You can play around these values to properly format data. For more information on formatting the output data refer Microsoft document for [Composite-Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component)

The following is the sample output:
[image]

Comment: You are a true hero! The only thing I can't figure out from reading what you did was the numbers in the curly brackets... Do you mind if I get a small explanation for that? If you don't have the time that's ok. Mainly I just want to say thank you!

Comment: @Alteridin, The numbers in curly braces are used for proper formatting of the string. Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component. Also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The approach looks like:

```
public void Print()
{
    Queue<Claims> allInQueue = _claimsRepo.GetClaims();

    PrintHeaders();
    foreach (var claim in allInQueue) 
    {
        PrintRow(claim);
    }
}

private void PrintHeaders()
{
    Console.Write("Claim ID"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.ClaimID)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Claim Type"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.ClaimType)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Description"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.ClaimDescription)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Amount"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.ClaimAmount)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Date of Accident"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.DateOfAccident)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Date of Claim"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.DateOfClaim)
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write("Valid Claim"); // or you can use nameof(Claim.IsValid)
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private void PrintRow(Claims claim)
{
    Console.Write(Claim.ClaimID);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.ClaimType);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.ClaimDescription);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.ClaimAmount);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.DateOfAccident);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.DateOfClaim);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(Claim.IsValid);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Of course, this printing is ugly. But it's a direction you should to dig in. 
As Benjamin Collins wrote you in comments:

> In general it's a matter of being patient and adding a bunch of | and _ characters and counting out spaces to make things look pretty.